# What is the format for writing Teradata Functions?

Tags: sql, function, view, teradata, user-defined-functions

For a project I'm working on we are asked to create Teradata Functions from Teradata Views, I looked on the documentation online, and I couldn't find any really clear examples on how the format should be written for this.

Does anyone have experience writing Teradata Functions in SQL or Java that could just give me a generic example of how to produce a function?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement? SQL-based UDFs are restricted to basic *Scalar Functions*. More complex UDFs (including *Table Operators* returning a result set) must be written in Java/C++

Comment: So essentially I'm trying to take a previous query I had written that was used for just basic data filtering (we can use this for an example: WHERE year = 1990, AND city = 'Miami') and transform this query so its parameters for YEAR and CITY can take in any input the user specifies. Does that help? I just want a function in teradata that can take in user inputs to filter the query instead of always going back and changing the WHERE clauses. And the work has to be done in teradata, so i dont know which of these (macros, procedures, views or functions) would be the best for that

Comment: How are the queries being executed?

Comment: Macro seems to fit this use case, provided the client can issue `EXEC` of the macro and then fetch a result set, rather than a `SELECT`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.